# Drop and create database in BootStrap

Tags: grails

I want to know if there is a way to drop and create database manually. I want to execute this code in the init method of BootStrap.groovy.

I am aware that we can set the dataSource to `create-drop` mode to achieve this when the application starts but I still want to have some sort of manual way to do this.

EDIT:

What I want to do is to clear my database and reload it with some dummy data while my app is running.

Comment: You can have a dbManger script that you can call in BootStrao.groovy

Answer (score 1):

You can have a dbManager script which will hold your manually customizing code.

Use below code into your **BootStrap.groovy** file to call your script.
It also runs based on your environment.

```
def dbManager =("grails -Dgrails.env="+Environment.currentEnvironment+" run-script scripts/dbManager.groovy").execute()
dbManager.waitForProcessOutput( System.out, System.err )
```

Comment: I need to know what to put in the "manually customizing code" for replicating the feature of create-drop of dataSource

Comment: You want to populate dummy data right, So you can delete previous records and add new onces through  code in  dbManager.groovy file

Comment: Yes, I am using manual sql scripts right now to do this which are called from BootStrap. The problem is not with loading data. It is with clearing it all up preferably using a command like dataSource.createDrop() i.e. if such a command exists.

Comment: I don't want to write manual sql to delete all dummy data. I want do it like grails dataSource. The dataSource (or maybe something else) clears up all the data in the tables when my application is stopped. I want to achieve similar function.